# Python: Como importar um modulo que ja está importando outro?

Tags: python, packages, import, módulo-python

Bem tenho a seguinte pasta:

```
src/
|- __init__.py
|- main.py
|_
  jogo/
  |-- __init__.py
  |-- play.py
  |_
    personagens/
    |--- __init__.py
    |--- heroi.py
```

heroi.py

```
def personagem_heroi():
  print("heroi")
```

play.py

```
import personagens.heroi

def iniciar_jogo():
  personagens.heroi.personagem_heroi()
  print("play")
```

Agora como faço para chamar o play atraves do main.py?

main.py

```
import jogo.play

jogo.pay.iniciar_jogo()

#ao importar aparece um erro de
```

```
import personagens.heroi

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'personagens'

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Tenta alterar no arquivo play onde tem `import personagens.heroi` para `from .personagens.heroi import personagem_heroi`.

Comment: Consegui o meu erro e que dentro do play eu tenho de importa dês da pasta raiz, segue abaixo a solução.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui o meu erro e que dentro do play eu tenho de importa dês da pasta raiz:

no main.py

```
from jogo import play

play.iniciar_jogo()
print("iniciar jogo")
```

no play.py

```
from jogo.personagens import heroi

def iniciar_jogo():
    heroi.personagem_heroi()
    print("play")
```

no heroi.py

```
def personagem_heroi():
    print("heroi")
```

pasta do arquivo:

```
src/
|- __init__.py
|- main.py
|_
  jogo/
  |-- __init__.py
  |-- play.py
  |_
    personagens/
    |--- __init__.py
    |--- heroi.py
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).